# Relationship between Young's moduli and "mixed" Shear modulus in transversely isotropic materials

Tags: classical-mechanics, elasticity, moduli

In isotropic elastic materials, the shear modulus, *G*, and the Young's modulus, *E*, are related via

$$
G = \frac{E}{2 (1 + \nu)}
$$

where $\nu$ is the Poisson ratio. As a consequence, as long as $\nu > -0.5$, $G < E$. I am interested in this relationship for transversely isotropic materials. Such materials have 5 instead of two independent constants: two Poisson ratios, two Young's moduli, and one "mixed" shear modulus. I am interested in the latter, as I need to reduce the number of independent constants in a fitting procedure. Are there any reasonable bounds or approximations for the mixed shear modulus? For example, one could use

$$
G_{m} \approx \frac{E_1 + E_2}{2}
$$

in rough analogy to the expression for the isotropic case (of course, any other form of mean/including the Poisson ratios may be equally (un)suited). Could this at all be justified? If not/alternatively, can the values of $E_1$ and $E_2$ be used to set bounds on $G_m$? For example, would $G_m$ need to be smaller than the larger of the two Young's moduli? I am grateful for any hint/opinion.

Comment: Instead of arithmetic mean, it is quite common in homogenization techniques to use the harmonic mean $2E_1E_2/(E_1+E_2)$, maybe that could have some interest here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your suspicion is justified: The stiffness tensor (or matrix if you will) has to be positive definite. In the transversal isotropic case you have 4 Eigenvalues and one "angle" (5 parameters in total), thus there are 4 inequalitis restricting your components, requiring positive eigenvalues

The full spectral decomposition of the transversal isotropic stiffness tensor can be found in Appendix A1 in this article

[Kalisch and Glüge 2015](http://ifm-hp15.mb.uni-magdeburg.de/gluege/SP/22.pdf)

In terms of the usual 6x6 Matrix representation, these inequalities hold:

$$C_{11} - C_{12}>0 $$
$$1/2 C_{11} + C_{12} - \sqrt{
   8 C_{13}^2 + (C_{11} + C_{12} - C_{33})^2} + C_{33}>0$$
$$1/2 C_{11} + C_{12} + \sqrt{
   8 C_{13}^2 + (C_{11} + C_{12} - C_{33})^2} + C_{33}>0$$
$$C_{44}>0$$

where $C_{ij}$ are the components of the stiffness tensor w.r.t. the non-normalized 6D basis for symmetric second order tensors. We see that the third equation is satisfied when the second one holds, so in effect there are 3 inequalities that constrain the 5 independent components.

This of course only limits the ranges of your components, probably just telling you that the moduli should be positive if expressed in components $C_{ij}$. AFAIK there are no approximations for the shear moduli except that they should be of the same order of magnitude as the in-plane and out-of-plane Young moduli. In terms of these components, the moduli are:

The in-plane Young modulus: $E_{inplane}=((C_{11}- C_{12}) (-2 C_{13}^2 + (C_{11} + C_{12}) C_{33}))/(-C_{13}^2 + C_{11} C_{33})$

The out-of-plane Young modulus: $E_{outofplane}=-((2 C_{13}^2)/(C_{11} + C_{12})) + C_{33}$

The shear modulus for in-plane shear: $G_{inplane}=C_{44}$

The shear modulus for out-of-plane shear $G_{outofplane}=(C_{11}-C_{22})/2$.

Maybe you can try to use these equations to relate your shear and Young moduli.

PS. I can provide more material if you need, just send a message.